# Notepad++ Replacing spaces between numbers with hyphen

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a a file that containes CSI codes used for construction billing. They are in the following format:

```
00 01 01 Project Title Page
00 01 05 Certifications Page
00 01 07 Seals Page
00 01 10 Table of Contents
00 01 15 List of Drawing Sheets
00 01 20 List of Schedules
```

We are changing the way employes name certain bidding files and I need to get this list to have the following format:

```
00-01-01 Project Title Page
00-01-05 Certifications Page
00-01-07 Seals Page
00-01-10 Table of Contents
00-01-15 List of Drawing Sheets
00-01-20 List of Schedules
```

I am very new to regex and I can not seem to get the replace part to work correctly. To search the file I am using the very simple [0-9] [0-9] . This highlights each section I am interested in changing. However, no matter what replace criteria I use I en up replacing the whole search statement with a hyphen. For the record I am using Notepad ++ and I do have it set to use regular expressions. I have tried many of the replace strings in other articles that have similar criteria with no success. Thank you for your time and consideration in this matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search for: `(\d)\s+(\d)`
Replace with: `$1-$2`

- The `(\d)`'s would be numbers, saved into capture groups
- The `\s+` would be any white space between the numbers
- In the replacement, we keep the capture groups `$1` and `$2` (the numbers), but put a hyphen between them instead of the whitespace that was there previously.

This will cover any situation I can see in "Replacing spaces between numbers with hyphen".

If you only want the specific scenario where you have 3 numbers all separated by a space, you could change the search to `(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)` and your replacement to `$1-$2-$3`

If you only want regular spaces and no tabs or whatever, you could replace `\s` with a simple space.

Comment: Thank you, I also found out that using the escape will work.\1-\2 . What is the significances of using the ()? is that what tells regex to remember whatever it finds? For example, it also works when I use ([0-9]) ([0-9]) in the search field with either $1-$2 or \1-\2 in the replace field.

Comment: @G.Oxsen, `\d` and `[0-9]` will work identically. also it appears `$1` and `\1` work the same way in the replace. The significance of `()` in regex is that it creates a "capture group". The first (0 index) capture group will always be the entire regex match, the second(1 index) will be the first capture group. I have to make it a capture group to basically "save" the data to use in the replace.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any capturing groups.

**Regex:**

```
(?<=\d) (?=\d)
```

**Replacement string:**

```
-
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/tM3aF5/11)

Comment: `(?<=^\d{2,2}) (\d+) ` => `-\1-` but this is really ugly :D

Comment: title `Replacing spaces between numbers with hyphen`. So this `(?<=\d) (?=\d)` would do the job well.

Answer (score 1):

### Notepad++ built-in features

There is no need to use a regex, you can use the Notepad++ built-in features to do this.

You have to go to <kbd>Edit</kbd> -> <kbd>Column Mode</kbd>:

[image]

[image]

[image]

### Find / Replace with regex

If you still want to use a regex. Then you can do something like this:

[image]

You can search for: `^(\d\d)\s(\d\d)\s`

And replace by: `\1-\2-`

Answer (score 0):

1. CTRL+F (in windows)
2. replace
3. regex  ☑
4. search `^(\d+) (\d+) (\d+)`, replacement `\1-\2-\3`

   - the `^` is the beginning of the line (so it won't match anything in the texts accidentally)
   - the `()` are capturing group beginning and end
   - the `\d+` are multiple digits
   - you don't need any special sign for normal spaces (if they are different whitespace characters, you can use the `\s` instead of )
   - the `\1`, `\2`, `\3` are the actual matches of the capturing groups

   *with only 2 capturing groups you'd have to click on the replace all button twice and left out the `^` from the beginning*
5. replace all